# FileNotFoundError when using listdir()

Tags: git, python-3.5

I am listing a bunch of bare git repositories in the `/mirror` folder as seen below:

```
def pusher():
    push_list = list()
    for repo in listdir("/mirrors"):
        remote_repo = repo.rsplit('.')
        push_list.append(remote_repo[0])
    logger.info("repositories to push: %s" % push_list)
    listdir("/mirror")
```

The `for` loop successfully adds the directories to a list after splitting off the `.git` on the end of the directory name. However, when I go to just execute `listdir()` after the `for` loop, I get this:

```
[03:47:52] INFO [root.pusher:64] repositories to push: ['a', 'b', 'c', ..., 'z']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mirror.py", line 90, in <module>
    pusher()
  File "mirror.py", line 65, in pusher
    listdir('/mirror')
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/mirror'
```

[Full code with minor redactions](https://gist.github.com/mynameismevin/9ac77371813905f2a8fd). What is causing it to fail on the second `listdir()`, but not the one in the `for` loop?

I'm using Python 3.5 from the [python:3.5-onbuild](https://hub.docker.com/_/python/) Docker image. My container copies over an SSH key, then executes the script.

Comment: Your `for` loop uses `"/mirrors"`, plural; is that a typo? (or the reason for your error?)

Comment: Yeah, that was the problem. Thanks @DavidZ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the last line, `listdir("/mirror")` was misspelled; should be `"/mirrors"`. :(